# Как спарсить меняющуюся ссылку на json python?

Tags: python, веб-скрейпинг

Есть код, который авторизуется на сайте, после чего я хотел бы забирать информацию, но сайт мне ее не отдает, покопавшись в запросах, я нашел json, думаю скопирую ссылку на него, но не тут то было, в ссылке есть место(sesskey), которое меняется с каждой авторизацией и из-за этого, перейдя в новой вкладе по этой ссылке выводится ошибка, как мне быть в данной ситуации, я хочу забрать этот json, но у меня не выходит. Немного покопавшись в том, что мне отдает сайт через парсер, я нашел класс в котором храниться ключ, который подойдет для меняющейся ссылки на json, но почему-то все равно не получается

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
session = requests.Session()
link = 'https://moodle.asu.edu.ru/login/index.php'

user = fake_useragent.UserAgent()
headers = {
    'User-Agent': user.random
}

response = session.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
login_token = soup.find('input', {'name': "logintoken"})['value']

data = {
    "logintoken": login_token,
    "username": '********',
    "password": '*******'
}
response = session.post(link, data=data, headers=headers)

profile_info = 'https://moodle.asu.edu.ru'
profile_response = session.get(profile_info)
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(profile_response.text, 'lxml')
soup2 = soup1.select_one('.logininfo')  # Место, где храниться ключ
soup3 = str(soup2).split('=')[-1].split('"')[0]
profile_info1 = f'https://moodle.asu.edu.ru/lib/ajax/service.php?sesskey={soup3}&info=core_calendar_get_action_events_by_timesort'
profile_response1 = session.get(profile_info1)
soup11 = BeautifulSoup(profile_response1.text, 'lxml')
print(soup11)
```